# Protecting a workbook with macro's using Userinterface only with Autofilter does not work

Tags: excel, vba

Protecting a workbook with a lot of macro's using Userinterfaceonly in combination with Autofilter does not work in ThisWorkBook; once relevant macro's are run error 1004 shows up and VBA still requires to unprotect the relevant sheets and debugs to lines with autofilter.

I have tried adding:

Add `Allowfiltering:= true` same errormessage.

Add `"Sheet".EnableAutoFiltering = True`  same errormessage.

Does anybody have a working solution or know of a problem with userinterfaceonly in combination with autofilter?

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    'Protect worksheets except for unlocked cells and macro's.
    Dim wSheet As Worksheet

    For Each wSheet In Worksheets
        wSheet.Protect Password:="123", UserInterFaceOnly:=True
    Next wSheet
End Sub
```

Expected result is that the macro's can be executed, including autofilters. The actual result is

> error 1004 sheet is protected, first unprotect.

Comment: In which line does this error occur? Try `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` instead. And of course you need to close and re-open the workbook before it is active (after changing code in `Workbook_Open`).

Comment: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets does not solve it unfortunately. The workbook consists of many sheets with many macro's and among them Advanced filters (I mentioned autofilter whereas I meant Advanced filter, stop the clock. sorry). The debug comes up at every macro that has an advanced filter in it. I have put all filters on different sheets than where the macro button is located, so the macro always jumps to another sheet for the filter.

Comment: I assume this can not be solved?